# how to use result of stored proc in IN operator within select?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a stored proc (lets name it **Proc1**) that returns set of ID's (integers) through relatively complicated selects.

Procedure **Proc1** returns recordset looking like this:

ID

_ _

123

234

55555

677889

Now, I would like to create a function which will return varchar as a result of algoritm within this function but I faced a problem because I can't write something like:

```
select something from tbl where tbl.id in (exec Proc1 @FunctionInputParam)
```

Could you explain how to use such stored proc in IN operator?

EDIT:
MSSQL 2012

Comment: all this "relatively complicated selects" are only `SELECT` statements? if yes, create a function instead of a procedure so you can use it later `in( select col from myView)`

Comment: Well, yes, this is possible to do. In this stored proc1 I'm calling another storedproc, then iterating cursor... shall see

Comment: oh, I'm afraid it won't be suitable for a view. Add schema and data sample, maybe this cursor could be replaced. And don't forget to take a look at this:The XY Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: yes... I'm very lazy guy, I wouldn't write functions if I'm not forced to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

Are all this "relatively complicated selects" only `SELECT` statements? if yes, create a function instead of a procedure so you can use it later

```
select something from tbl where tbl.id in( select col from myView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I know of is a temporary table or table variable, and insert the results from the proc, then use that in your `in`:

```
declare @tmp table (i int);
insert @tmp exec Proc1 @FunctionInputParam;
select something from tbl where tbl.id in (select i from @tmp);
```

Comment: please, when @tmp variable gonna be killed, collected... ?

Comment: It is a variable like any other. It will be removed as soon as the batch completes. It does not behave any differently than any other variable.

Comment: @joe unfortunately this appears as a same problem: 
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

Comment: @dllhell Yep, forgot about that - functions don't allow this. If there's any way you can change your function into a stored proc (maybe by using an output parameter or selected value instead of a return value), you can do this. Otherwise, if you can do this outside of the function, and use a temp table (`#tmp` instead of `@tmp`) instead - you should be able to access the table from inside the function, even though it was created elsewhere.

Comment: I'd also recommend [this article](http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html) - I don't know if it's got a solution to your problem specifically, but it's an excellent read on sharing data between stored procs, might give you some inspiration.

Comment: @joe idea was to put this function call in some other select for grid view, I don't believe I can put storedproc into select as column. Thaks for your effort kind sir!